# Splitting a `char[]` in C++

Tags: c++

I have a `char[]` in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.

e.g. 2011052504572

I want to retrieve the year, month, date, hour, minute and second from this char. How do I do that?

NOTE:I cant use any third party dll.

Thanks,
Syd

Comment: That's a pretty long character. Is it possible that you have a *string*?

Comment: If the string is always in that format this should be pretty simple..what have you tried so far?

Comment: Most likely it's a char* or char[]

Comment: @syd: a `char` in C++ is a character. In every commonly used implementation, it is 8 bits wide, big enough to store a single ASCII character. A sequence of characters is called *a string*. What you probably have is a *char pointer* (`char*`, with the asterisk), which points to a string, or a *char array* (`char[]`), storing a string

Comment: I have already edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string::substr()` for this purpose. Example,

```
  string date = "20110524112233";

  string year = date.substr(0, 4);
  string month = date.substr(4, 2);
  string day = date.substr(6, 2);
  string hour = date.substr(8, 2);
  string minute = date.substr(10, 2);
  string second = date.substr(12, 2);
```

Comment: Your are missing the time part in the test string.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the STL then just put the string into a **std::string** and use the **substr** method:

```
std::string dateTime=......;

std::string year=dateTime.substr(0,4);
std::string month=dateTime.substr(4,2);
// etc
// etc
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you want to extract the values as text, or convert them to numbers.  For getting lots of strings, you can use `std::string` and `substr()` as thoroughly illustrated in other answers.

If you want to get numbers that you can then calculate with, then one approach is:

```
int year, month, day, hour, minute, second;

if (sscanf(input, "%.4d%.2d%.2d%.2d%.2d%.2d",
           &year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second) == 6)
{
    // all 6 conversions worked... can use the values...

    int second_in_day = hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second;
    ...
}
```

Another approach is to use `strptime()` - if your system has it.  It parses a string into a broken-down-time structure:

```
struct tm tm;
strptime(input, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &tm);
// parsed values are in tm.tm_year, tm.tm_mon, tm.tm_mday,
//                      tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec
// further, tm_wday has day of week, tm_yday has day in year
// i.e. it actually understands the date, not just chopping up numbers/text
```

Note: `sscanf()` and `strncpy()` are C functions callable from C++, and they're not as safe to use as C++-specific functionality (`std::string`, `std::istringstream`) in that small misunderstandings and mistakes in handling the data can lead to not just erroneous results, but program crashes.  So, read the manual pages for these things carefully if you use them.

Comment: I general recommend against `scanf`, but in this case: `scanf` respects the precision argument when inputting integers, `istream` doesn't.  It's worth considering whether this advantage outweighs the well known disadvantages (safety, etc.).  It might.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strncpy`... okay, so if it is not homework, then this is the best way.  The others using std::string are wasting resources:

```
static const char *yyyymmddhhmmss = "20110526101559";
char year[5] = { '\0' };
char month[3] = { '\0' };
char day[3] = { '\0' };
char hour[3] = { '\0' };
char minute[3] = { '\0' };
char second[3] = { '\0' };
strncpy(year, yyyymmddhhmmss, 4);
strncpy(month, &yyyymmddhhmmss[4], 2);
strncpy(day, &yyyymmddhhmmss[6], 2);
strncpy(hour, &yyyymmddhhmmss[8], 2);
strncpy(minute, &yyyymmddhhmmss[10], 2);
strncpy(second, &yyyymmddhhmmss[12], 2);
```

Comment: No its is not homework. I am new to c++ and I have no idea which method to use to split the char.

Comment: The question is tagged `c++`.

Comment: The above is efficient in c or c++.  There is no reason to use std::string.

Comment: Using std::string is the simplest method.
What is most efficient?
Efficiency is not only about saving a few clock cycles.
It also about saving development time and writing code that is easier to maintain.

Comment: @user763305 - fair point about 'efficiency', however, that code is just as easy to understand and maintain if one understands c/c++, and it runs faster with less resources - which was my point about wasting resources in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the input in the form of a `char[]` (or `char*`—for
this use, it comes out to the same thing), the simplest solution is
probably using the two iterator constructors for `std::string` to creat
a string for each field, e.g.:

```
std::string year ( date    , date + 4 );
std::string month( date + 4, date + 6 );
std::string day  ( date + 6, date + 8 );
//  ...
```

If you need the numerical values, `boost::lexical_cast` can be used,
e.g.:

```
int extractField( char const* string, int begin, int end )
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<int>(
            std::string( date + begin, date + end ) );
}

int year = extractField( date, 0, 4 );
int year = extractField( date, 4, 6 );
//  ...
```